Why am I getting a Powershell ImportExcel error if I've already installed the module?
First time posting a question, sorry in advance.  I don't know why I keep getting the below ImportExcel message.  I've run 'Install-module -Name ImportExcel' multiple times.  Other members of my team can run in with no issue.  I tried Import-Excel with no luck. I'm stumped.
'c:_it\scripts\elevate\callreport\CallSummary 03-09-2024.xlsx' file not found
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ImportExcel\7.8.6\Public\Import-Excel.ps1:119 char:21


                throw "'$($Path)' file not found"



                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: ('c:_it\scripts... file not found:String) [], RuntimeException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : 'c:_it\scripts\elevate\callreport\CallSummary 03-09-2024.xlsx' file not found



I've tried Install-module, Import-module the ImportExcel and Import-Excel.  Restarting PS, uninstalling the module.

c:_it should be probably c:\it. typo.

@Mr.Key7 the module is already installed, the error is indeed coming from a function from that module. OP is simply using an incorrect path.

you should include your script code in question. so, we can correct it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
